# Get status of single line

Tags: android, android-singleline

We can set single line with this

```
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.someTextView);
textView.setSingleLine(true);
```

But for get status of single line event `getSingleLine()` does not exit.

How can check that single line for text view is on (true) or off (false)?

My target API level is 15.

Comment: I added support for API 15 with singleLine in my previous answer

Answer (score 3):

I believe singleLine is deprecated, you should use `textView.setMaxLines(1)` instead and then use `textView.getMaxLines()` so to know if textViewis singleLine :

```
boolean isSingleLine = textView.getMaxLines() == 1;
```

**EDIT FOR API 15**

But in case you are using `singleLine` in that case to know if the TextView is singleLine you can use `getTransformationMethod()` available from API 1 onwards like so :

```
boolean isSingleLine = textView.getTransformationMethod() == SingleLineTransformationMethod.getInstance();
```

Comment: return textView.getMaxLines() == 1; would suffice

Comment: @WilliMentzel yep you're right, but I prefer writing it like this for clarity of explanation but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: why the downvote ? Perfectly valid answer, user added API 15 only after the answer had been posted

Comment: no downvote: but why did you edit your answer, after explaining to me why you don't write it the way I proposed :D? plus the return is totally out of context.. you should wrap it in a method

Comment: @WilliMentzel I said you were right and I edited it based on your suggestion I just have the bad habit of putting 'if' everywhere when explaining :p

Comment: wrap it in a method a la isSingleLine or remove the return that would really improve your answer! i would go for option one

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`getMaxLines()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getMaxLines()).

```
tv.setSingleLine( true ) || tv.setMaxLines( 1 );

int maxLines = tv.getMaxLines();

Assert.assertTrue( 1, maxLines );
```

The docs for [`setSingleLine()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setSingleLine()) say that:

> Sets the properties of this field (lines, horizontally scrolling, transformation method) to be for a single-line input.

My undesrtanding of this, is that they are juts putting a nice wrapper around `setMaxLines(1)` and some others.

And [under the covers](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L7877), this method does indeed set the line count to 1.

Comment: But `getMaxLines()` need API level 16 or higher

Comment: You should be using a compat library that still gives you these features. Your question also does not specify a target API, so this is perfectly valid,